# Hibernate insert null values ​in composite foreign key

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I have two simple domain objects as follows:

USER:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@IdClass(UserPK.class)
public class User implements Serializable {

    //...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "FISCALCODE")
    private String fiscalCode;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USERNUMBER")
    private String userNumber;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Items> items;
    
    // getters and setters
}
```

UserPK:

```java
public class UserPK implements Serializable {
        
  @Column(name = "FISCALCODE")
  private String fiscalCode;
    
  @Column(name = "USERNUMBER")
  private String userNumber;

  // getter and setter
}
```

ITEMS:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="ITEMS")
public class Items implements Serializable {
        
    //...
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID_ITEM")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "id_item_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator( name = "id_item_generator", sequenceName = "ITEM_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    private Integer id;
            
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
         @JoinColumn(name="FISCALCODE"),
         @JoinColumn(name="USERNUMBER")
    })
    private User user;
        
    // getters and setters
}
```

DB Table:

```
user { fiscalcode, usernumber, other columns... }    // fiscalcode+usernumber = PK
items { id, fiscalcode, usernumber, other columns... }  // fiscalcode,usernumber is a foreign key

CONTROLLER:  

      @RequestMapping(value="/user", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = "application/json")
        public Object postUser(@RequestBody(required = false) User user){
        //connection etc..
        session.save(user);
        //...
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
      }
```

Why when I run the command `session.save(user)` Hibernate insert value null in the columns `FISCALCODE` and `USERNUMBER` of the `ITEMS` table?

I tried to set the `ManyToOne` and the `JoinColumns` on the getter, but the result is the same.

EDIT: i have added my method for POST operation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As it's stated in the [documentation](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/JoinColumns.html) for `@JoinColumns`:

> When the `JoinColumns` annotation is used, both the `name` and the `referencedColumnName` elements must be specified in each such `JoinColumn` annotation.

So, you should correct your mapping like below:

```java
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="FISCALCODE", referencedColumnName = "FISCALCODE"),
    @JoinColumn(name="USERNUMBER", referencedColumnName = "USERNUMBER")
})
private User user;
```

2. Whenever a bidirectional association is formed, the application developer must make sure both sides are in-sync at all times.

So, you should have in your `User` entity the `addItem()` and `removeItem()` utility methods that synchronize both ends whenever a child element is added or removed like below.

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@IdClass(UserPK.class)
public class User implements Serializable {

    //...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Items> items;
    
    // getters and setters

   public void addItem(Items item) {
      this.items.add(item);
      item.setUser(this);
   }

   public void removeItem(Items item) {
      this.items.remove(item);
      item.setUser(null);
   }
}
```

Example of saving:

```java
User user = new User();
user.setFiscalCode("Code1");
user.setUserNumber("User1");
// ...

Items item1 = new Items();
Items item2 = new Items();
// ...
      
user.addItem(item1);
user.addItem(item2);
      
session.save(user);
```

Comment: i have already tried to add referencedColumnName, but the result doesn't change

Comment: See updated answer, you should sync both sides of bidirectional association.

Comment: I added the add and remove methods to the items class but it keeps inserting null values ​​in the foreign key of the ITEMS table.I am desperate

Comment: in debug I noticed that inside the user object, if I open the list of items, the single item has inside the null value associated with the user object. I don't know if I've made myself clear

Comment: I modified the question by adding my post method which goes to save the object

Comment: I have added an example that show how entities should be initialized before saving.

Comment: so it might work but my object is auto serialized from the input json

Comment: It's just common mistake when you try to use domain model (entities) in client - server intercommunication. It can work for very simple example but it will not work for more complex cases. The common practice here just introduce one more layer for client - server intercommunication (DTOs).

Comment: thank you! mapping through a DTO and setting User inside each Item I solved the problem!